# Kubernetes networking and firewall issue

Tags: networking, kubernetes, kubeadm, flannel

I try to expose a service. The goal is to access it from a cli (who know nothing about the cluster) with just his ip.

I  have create a deployment of the image and then create the service by exposing it with nodport type.

When I expose it on port 80, I can access to the svc but no other port working.
I have try with adding iptables rules but not working.
k8s doesn't do it automaticaly ?

I use kubeadm on centos

```
swapoff -a
systemctl disable firewalld
systemctl stop firewalld
setenforce 0
```

iptables-save

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Tue May 29 14:36:29 2018
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [4:812]
:INPUT ACCEPT [4:812]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2:120]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2:120]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:KUBE-MARK-DROP - [0:0]
:KUBE-MARK-MASQ - [0:0]
:KUBE-NODEPORTS - [0:0]
:KUBE-POSTROUTING - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-5GE65UWKUZXJBCHC - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-7PPXA5JT5ALVQPIV - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-CTNKE6SP4U52GYW7 - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-FO2LZ42N5CRZ6GVT - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-HWIIVMKETERLJ5EZ - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-IWBXS2W6OTONAINX - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-JMXD3AUAOAUBCCUM - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-PGKOTXVCEGHQUOMC - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-SNPTLXDNVSPZ5ND2 - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-T3255DXCOSMHHF7M - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-ZKRGYSR5PGCBUGKL - [0:0]
:KUBE-SERVICES - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-BJM46V3U5RZHCFRZ - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-EM2CH54TJVNBSB67 - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4 - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-GRFCLVVBA4S2E2F4 - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-JRXTEHDDTAFMSEAS - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-Q6XJQ2I55QTBQCWT - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-XGLOHA7QRQ3V22RZ - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes postrouting rules" -j KUBE-POSTROUTING
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.244.0.0/16 -d 10.244.0.0/16 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.244.0.0/16 ! -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING ! -s 10.244.0.0/16 -d 172.25.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING ! -s 10.244.0.0/16 -d 10.244.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A KUBE-MARK-DROP -j MARK --set-xmark 0x8000/0x8000
-A KUBE-MARK-MASQ -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4000/0x4000
-A KUBE-NODEPORTS -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/dark-svc:" -m tcp --dport 30047 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-NODEPORTS -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/dark-svc:" -m tcp --dport 30047 -j KUBE-SVC-GRFCLVVBA4S2E2F4
-A KUBE-NODEPORTS -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/dark-svc2:" -m tcp --dport 32205 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-NODEPORTS -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/dark-svc2:" -m tcp --dport 32205 -j KUBE-SVC-EM2CH54TJVNBSB67
-A KUBE-POSTROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes service traffic requiring SNAT" -m mark --mark 0x4000/0x4000 -j MASQUERADE
-A KUBE-SEP-5GE65UWKUZXJBCHC -s 172.17.0.9/32 -m comment --comment "default/dark-svc:" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-5GE65UWKUZXJBCHC -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/dark-svc:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.9:80
-A KUBE-SEP-7PPXA5JT5ALVQPIV -s 172.17.0.2/32 -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-7PPXA5JT5ALVQPIV -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:53
-A KUBE-SEP-CTNKE6SP4U52GYW7 -s 172.17.0.5/32 -m comment --comment "kube-system/monitoring-influxdb:" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-CTNKE6SP4U52GYW7 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/monitoring-influxdb:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.5:8086
-A KUBE-SEP-FO2LZ42N5CRZ6GVT -s 172.17.0.10/32 -m comment --comment "default/dark-svc:" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-FO2LZ42N5CRZ6GVT -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/dark-svc:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.10:80
-A KUBE-SEP-HWIIVMKETERLJ5EZ -s 172.17.0.9/32 -m comment --comment "default/dark-svc2:" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-HWIIVMKETERLJ5EZ -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/dark-svc2:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.9:8085
-A KUBE-SEP-IWBXS2W6OTONAINX -s 172.17.0.4/32 -m comment --comment "kube-system/monitoring-grafana:" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-IWBXS2W6OTONAINX -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/monitoring-grafana:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.4:3000
-A KUBE-SEP-JMXD3AUAOAUBCCUM -s 172.17.0.10/32 -m comment --comment "default/dark-svc2:" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-JMXD3AUAOAUBCCUM -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/dark-svc2:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.10:8085
-A KUBE-SEP-PGKOTXVCEGHQUOMC -s 10.66.222.223/32 -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-PGKOTXVCEGHQUOMC -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https" -m recent --set --name KUBE-SEP-PGKOTXVCEGHQUOMC --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.66.222.223:6443
-A KUBE-SEP-SNPTLXDNVSPZ5ND2 -s 172.17.0.2/32 -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-SNPTLXDNVSPZ5ND2 -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -m udp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:53
-A KUBE-SEP-T3255DXCOSMHHF7M -s 172.17.0.6/32 -m comment --comment "kube-system/heapster:" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-T3255DXCOSMHHF7M -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/heapster:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.6:8082
-A KUBE-SEP-ZKRGYSR5PGCBUGKL -s 172.17.0.8/32 -m comment --comment "kube-system/kubernetes-dashboard:" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-ZKRGYSR5PGCBUGKL -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kubernetes-dashboard:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.8:8443
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 172.25.0.0/16 -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 53 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 53 -j KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 172.25.0.0/16 -d 10.108.154.85/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/monitoring-influxdb: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 8086 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.108.154.85/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/monitoring-influxdb: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 8086 -j KUBE-SVC-Q6XJQ2I55QTBQCWT
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 172.25.0.0/16 -d 10.100.27.82/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/dark-svc: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 80 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.100.27.82/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/dark-svc: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 80 -j KUBE-SVC-GRFCLVVBA4S2E2F4
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 172.25.0.0/16 -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns cluster IP" -m udp --dport 53 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns cluster IP" -m udp --dport 53 -j KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 172.25.0.0/16 -d 10.108.155.161/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/heapster: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 80 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.108.155.161/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/heapster: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 80 -j KUBE-SVC-BJM46V3U5RZHCFRZ
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 172.25.0.0/16 -d 10.96.203.18/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kubernetes-dashboard: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 443 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.96.203.18/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kubernetes-dashboard: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 443 -j KUBE-SVC-XGLOHA7QRQ3V22RZ
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 172.25.0.0/16 -d 10.102.95.216/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/monitoring-grafana: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 80 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.102.95.216/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/monitoring-grafana: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 80 -j KUBE-SVC-JRXTEHDDTAFMSEAS
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 172.25.0.0/16 -d 10.107.240.220/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/dark-svc2: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 8085 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.107.240.220/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/dark-svc2: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 8085 -j KUBE-SVC-EM2CH54TJVNBSB67
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 172.25.0.0/16 -d 10.96.0.1/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 443 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.96.0.1/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 443 -j KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y
-A KUBE-SERVICES -m comment --comment "kubernetes service nodeports; NOTE: this must be the last rule in this chain" -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j KUBE-NODEPORTS
-A KUBE-SVC-BJM46V3U5RZHCFRZ -m comment --comment "kube-system/heapster:" -j KUBE-SEP-T3255DXCOSMHHF7M
-A KUBE-SVC-EM2CH54TJVNBSB67 -m comment --comment "default/dark-svc2:" -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.50000000000 -j KUBE-SEP-JMXD3AUAOAUBCCUM
-A KUBE-SVC-EM2CH54TJVNBSB67 -m comment --comment "default/dark-svc2:" -j KUBE-SEP-HWIIVMKETERLJ5EZ
-A KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4 -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp" -j KUBE-SEP-7PPXA5JT5ALVQPIV
-A KUBE-SVC-GRFCLVVBA4S2E2F4 -m comment --comment "default/dark-svc:" -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.50000000000 -j KUBE-SEP-FO2LZ42N5CRZ6GVT
-A KUBE-SVC-GRFCLVVBA4S2E2F4 -m comment --comment "default/dark-svc:" -j KUBE-SEP-5GE65UWKUZXJBCHC
-A KUBE-SVC-JRXTEHDDTAFMSEAS -m comment --comment "kube-system/monitoring-grafana:" -j KUBE-SEP-IWBXS2W6OTONAINX
-A KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https" -m recent --rcheck --seconds 10800 --reap --name KUBE-SEP-PGKOTXVCEGHQUOMC --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j KUBE-SEP-PGKOTXVCEGHQUOMC
-A KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https" -j KUBE-SEP-PGKOTXVCEGHQUOMC
-A KUBE-SVC-Q6XJQ2I55QTBQCWT -m comment --comment "kube-system/monitoring-influxdb:" -j KUBE-SEP-CTNKE6SP4U52GYW7
-A KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -j KUBE-SEP-SNPTLXDNVSPZ5ND2
-A KUBE-SVC-XGLOHA7QRQ3V22RZ -m comment --comment "kube-system/kubernetes-dashboard:" -j KUBE-SEP-ZKRGYSR5PGCBUGKL
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue May 29 14:36:29 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Tue May 29 14:36:29 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [2819:674508]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2766:742748]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION - [0:0]
:KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES - [0:0]
:KUBE-FIREWALL - [0:0]
:KUBE-FORWARD - [0:0]
:KUBE-SERVICES - [0:0]
:LOGGING - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes externally-visible service portals" -j KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
-A INPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 35055 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j LOGGING
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding rules" -j KUBE-FORWARD
-A FORWARD -s 10.244.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.244.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A OUTPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
-A KUBE-FIREWALL -m comment --comment "kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets" -m mark --mark 0x8000/0x8000 -j DROP
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding rules" -m mark --mark 0x4000/0x4000 -j ACCEPT
-A KUBE-FORWARD -s 172.25.0.0/16 -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod source rule" -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A KUBE-FORWARD -d 172.25.0.0/16 -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod destination rule" -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue May 29 14:36:29 2018
```

kubectl cluster-info

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://10.66.222.223:6443
Heapster is running at https://10.66.222.223:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/proxy
KubeDNS is running at https://10.66.222.223:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
monitoring-grafana is running at https://10.66.222.223:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana/proxy
monitoring-influxdb is running at https://10.66.222.223:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-influxdb/proxy
```

kubectl get pods

```
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
dark-room-dep-577bf64bb8-9n5p7   1/1       Running   0          4d
dark-room-dep-577bf64bb8-jmppg   1/1       Running   0          4d
```

kubectl get svc

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
dark-svc     NodePort    10.100.27.82     <none>        80:30047/TCP     1d
dark-svc2    NodePort    10.107.240.220   <none>        8085:32205/TCP   4h
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          12d
```

from master node:
curl 10.66.222.223

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.66.222.223:80; Connexion refusée
```

curl 127.0.0.1

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:80; Connexion refusée
```

from a firefox client it working fine.

If I try an other port:
curl 10.66.222.223:8085

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.66.222.223:8085; Connexion refusée
```

curl 127.0.0.1:8085

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:8085; Connexion refusée
```

and when i try on firefox client it give me a connection refused.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: what's the output of `curl http://<node_ip>:80`?

Also, _When I expose it on port 80, I can access to the svc but no other port working_. Which other port are you trying to access? List the output.

Answer (score 1):

You did not expose your service on port 80 with your NodePort Service. Let's take a look at the output you provided:

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
dark-svc     NodePort    10.100.27.82     <none>        80:30047/TCP     1d
dark-svc2    NodePort    10.107.240.220   <none>        8085:32205/TCP   4h
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          12d
```

The *PORT* section of your output describes port mapping. The service `dark-svc` has endpoint (pods matched by that service) port `80` mapped to NodePort `30047`. NodePort is the port exposed on your Kubernetes nodes. See [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport) section of the Kubernetes documentation for more information on the NodePort service type.

Therefore, you need to curl `http://<node ip>:30047` to access the service you were trying to access.